# In assembly Intel x64 why should place square brackets around stdin

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, dereference

Today was doing exercise with calling *fgets* from assembly.
For passing FILE* to file stream I wrote `mov rdx, [stdin]`.

**But why it should be in square brackets**? Because I do not need value of that pointer just the pointer itself. Should mention, that lea rdx, [stdin] also does not work. As I remember, it causes SIGSEGV to be sent to program.

As I understand square brackets in operand of `mov` instruction mean same as dereferencing pointer in C. Also I know that libc is dynamically linked to my executable at runtime and mapped somewhere between the stack and heap of program's virtual memory address space.

YASM, glibc, Linux x64.

Comment: @EmployedRussian: I left the glibc tag in when editing since it was a question about `FILE *stdin`.  (The answer was unrelated to that, of course, but I could imagine another person searching for the same issue thinking it was something to do with glibc.)  There's also a `libc` tag; would that be more appropriate?

Comment: @PeterCordes But `FILE *stdin` doesn't have much to do with GLIBC either: every other libc provides it. And I don't think `libc` tag is called for either: the question is not about the library, but about a global variable of pointer type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FILE *stdin;` is a global variable of pointer type.  That means the value stored at the static location is the pointer you want.  Since the *value* we want to pass is a pointer stored at the location labelled with `stdin`, we need to load from `[stdin]` instead of passing the address of the `stdin` symbol.

Passing the address of `stdin` (with `lea rdx, [rel stdin]`) would work if it was declared as `FILE stdin`, and used in C as `fgets(buf, size, &stdin)`.

---

libc's definition of `FILE *stdin;` is equivalent to this asm.

```
section .data
stdin: dq  stdin_FILE_struct           ; This is a pointer stored in memory

section .bss
...
stdin_FILE_struct:           ;; TOTALLY MADE UP, it's not actually like this
    resq 1                       ; something
    resd 1                       ; something_else
    resb 4096                    ; buffer
```

`stdin` might actually be in the BSS, and the data it points to may well be dynamically allocated by glibc init functions.

`stdin` is an opaque pointer.  You don't need to care what it points to, just that it holds a pointer to the actual `FILE` object, and that's what you need to pass to fgets.

Comment: In c it is easy to understand, but why in assembly we use brackets around [stdin]. Why we dereference the pointer when we need just the pointer inself?
Yes, I understand the difference between mov rdx, stdin and mov rdx, [stdin]. And I do not understand why second variant works.

Comment: @BulatM. That is the question I'm answering.  I added another sentence to make it even more clear.

Comment: But if it is declared like FILE *stdin(man 3 stdio on my box) in libc headers? How to use it in assembly?

Comment: Look at compiler output for using a normal `int` global variable: https://godbolt.org/g/3TgRbd.  Just because the global is holding a pointer value doesn't mean you pass the address when the C is passing a variable by value.

Comment: Indeed, what mean rel in lea rdx, [rel stdin]?

Comment: The same thing as `DEFAULT REL` in NASM: use RIP-relative addressing instead of absolute addresses when you write `[stdin]`.

Comment: What is the benefit of RIP-relative addressing compared to absolute, which is preferred?